# Django: how to use {{ something }} inside css file

Tags: django

I have a model called `Post` with a `FileField` which is an image.

I want to do something like this:

```
.article-image{
    background-image: url("../img/{{ post.postimage }});
}
```

but obviously it does not work, so I tried to make inline css instead:

```
<div class="article-image" style="background-image:{% static 'img/{{ post.postimage }}' %}"></div>
```

but it does not work too.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

for the first case you can't do that because it's CSS file not Django template.
but for the second case, you can use template tags like this

create templatetags/my_custom_tag.py in your app and add the following code into it.

```
from django import template
from your_base_app.settings import STATIC_URL

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def show_image(img):
    return STATIC_URL + 'img/' + img;
```

you should load your tags in the top of your django template like that

```
{% load my_custom_tag %}
```

your django template should be like this

```
<div class="article-image" style="background-image:url({% show_image post.postimage.url %})"></div>
```

Comment: don't forget to import STATIC_URL from your settings

Comment: my static url is /static/ so can I hard code it ? it never changes

Comment: what do you mean hard code it? do you mean like that style="background-image: /static/img/'{{ post.postimage }}' " ?

Comment: what is templatetags ? is it a file or a directory and where do I create it

Comment: it's directory, you should create it inside your app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194328/discussion-between-omar-and-qux).